# minkube dashboard command hangs on 'verifying proxy health'

Tags: kubernetes, minikube

I'm taking a Kubernetes course and part of the course is trying out minikube. I have minikube and kubectl installed on an Ubuntu 20.04 WSL on Windows 11. When I run `minikube dashboard` in the Ubuntu terminal the process hangs on `Verifying proxy health...`. I tried running `kubectl proxy` in another terminal window then running `minikube dashboard`.
I go to the dashboard URL and use the proxy port number that the kubectl proxy command indicates but I only get this:

```
{
  "kind": "Status",
  "apiVersion": "v1",
  "metadata": {},
  "status": "Failure",
  "message": "no endpoints available for service \"kubernetes-dashboard\"",
  "reason": "ServiceUnavailable",
  "code": 503
}
```

I've also tried running minikube by using `minikube start --vm-driver=docker` as mentioned in this [GitHub issue](https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/9473#issuecomment-1001145166) but it still hangs. How do get the dashboard to run? I'm completely new to Kubernetes in general.

Answer (score 11):

For me the same issue was resolved after a restart of the minikube.

```
minikube stop
<close previously opened dashboard process> - for me ctrl+c in separate terminal, but maybe you'd have to kill it
minikube start
minikube dashboard
```

Answer (score 3):

It is worked for me after disabled metrics-server

```
minikube addons disable metrics-server
```

After disable, reenabled again and it continued to work.

```
minikube addons enable metrics-server
```

Answer (score 0):

At first when I tried to start the dashboard, the following error showed up:

> dashboard: The ClusterRoleBinding "kubernetes-dashboard" is invalid:
> cannot change roleRef

Using the provided in the terminal [link](https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/7256) I followed the steps in the answers and then the dashboard was stuck into the following error:

> Verifying the proxy health ...

Restarting minikube did not solved the problem.

Following steps fixed the issue:

1. Delete minikube container (through Docker Desktop or terminal)
2. Start minikube again - minikube start (which caused minikube container recreation)
3. minikube dashboard

Comment: Downvoting as you're answering another question (not asked) and then repeating previously submitted answers (2 months before you) without adding any useful or actionable information.

Answer (score 0):

FWIW I had this issue and it was due to docker not having enough space. It was easy to miss the warning message:

```
  Docker is nearly out of disk space, which may cause deployments to fail! (94% of capacity). You can pass '--force' to skip this check.
```

Cleaning up my docker resources (I had some veryt large experimental builds recently) the restarting minikube allows `minikube dashabord` to launch successfully. YMMV; you might instead allocate more space to docker (if that's what you're using)

Answer (score 0):

`minikube ssh`
Ensure Minikube can talk to the Internet.
Simple `ping google.com` will do.

Comment: it has connectivity to the internet but the dashboard process is still stuck at "Verifying proxy health..."

Comment: ping google.com fails, why is minikube not able to connect to the internet?

Answer (score 0):

I had to switch the docker context for it to work for me:

```
 docker context use default
```

Answer (score -1):

I had to do this to get it to work:

```
kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/dashboard/v2.0.0-beta8/aio/deploy/recommended.yaml

# Replace ClusterIP with NodePort (case sensitive)
kubectl edit svc kubernetes-dashboard -n kubernetes-dashboard
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this solution doesn't work. It leads to the error `no endpoints available for service "kubernetes-dashboard"` given by the proxy via the GUI. Changing `ClusterIP` doesn't change anything. I am using Linux Fedora 36.

Comment: This doesnt work for me..  after doing that... my kubernetes API went down..



STDERR:
  Error: Kubernetes cluster unreachable: Get "https://10.110.0.35:8443/version": dial tcp 10.110.0.35:8443: connect: connection refused

COMBINED OUTPUT:
  Error: Kubernetes cluster unreachable: Get "https://10.110.0.35:8443/version": dial tcp 10.110.0.35:8443: connect: connection refused

Answer (score -1):

Had the same issue with dashboard while trying to start minikube cluster and dashboard with slow and unstable internet connection. Started it with good internet and it worked. I am pretty new to kubernetes too, but it seems that it needs stable internet to work or at least to check proxy health.

Comment: minikube is supposed to run locally, so is the proxy. So the internet connection is most likely not a factor that will affect purely local services. Downvoting because there is no valid analysis of why retrying worked for you. Two events occuring at the same time don't necessarily share a root cause, coincidences exist.

Answer (score -2):

for me, it was updating docker desktop. Had a really old version and always snoozed on update prompts. Never used it that much.
After updating, it works as intended.